# Using Index Match with a Sum of a Range

Tags: google-sheets, indexing, range, sumifs

Using Google Sheets:

Here is my current formula that I am using to return the data from ONE Date and I am looking to duplicate this formula except SUM the data of a Date Range.

Current Formula:
=IFERROR(INDEX('Delavan Ford'!$AJ$3:$AJ$1000, MATCH ($B$1,'Delavan Ford'!$V$3:$V$1000,0)),"")

B1= the current single date field that it is looking for a match for and returning the data.
I would be adding another field in B2 to be the second date that it is looking for to return the sum of the data between the 2 dates.

Thanks.

Comment: Look into `SUMIFS`

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Answer (score 0):

SumIF or SumIFs should work. Personally I prefer to use the QUERY() function as I feel it is more intuitive.

Comment: This is not a answer. You can suggest this to comment.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `SUMIFS()` like-

```
=SUMIFS(A3:A,V3:V,">="&B1,V3:V,"<="&B2)
```

Or `QUERY()` function like-

```
=QUERY(A3:V,"select sum(A) 
where V>= date '" & TEXT(B1,"yyyy-mm-dd") & 
"' and V<= date '" & TEXT(B2,"yyyy-mm-dd") & 
"' label sum(A) ''")
```

Comment: Where would I insert that part in my existing formula of - Current Formula: =IFERROR(INDEX('Delavan Ford'!$AJ$3:$AJ$1000, MATCH ($B$1,'Delavan Ford'!$V$3:$V$1000,0)),"")

Comment: Replace your full formula with my one.